# How do I populate a grid with a list of list of object? in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What I have:

```
List<List<Object>> myListofList = new List<List<Object>>();
Mydatagridx.datasourse = myListofList;
```

And this gives me a grid with capacity and number of elements.
I tried something like this:

```
class newobj
    {
        public List<oldobj> listbig { get; set; }
    }
   foreach(var aux in Biggerlist)
    {
        //this is a row
         newobj.list = aux;
    }
    List<newobj> newobjList.add(newobj)
datagrid.datasource = newobjList;
```

But this does not work as it shows nothing.for the datasource, 
I need the internal for to be represented in horizontal (atached columns) and
the external one changes the row for each row represent a user.
I think maybe a datatable may work but no idea how i would go about to make one that adapts to a variable lenght at the creation.

Any ideas out there? I dont want to show all the objects in rows with no filter what so ever.
I am sorry for not being more expresive but i just cant wrap my mind on how to do it.

Comment: Basically each data row is going to be a list, which the DataGrid doesn't know how to bind to.  You'll probably need to override the `RowsAdded` event to control exactly how each column gets populated.